# PuPHPet - Vagrant Errors: Evaluation Error and non-zero exit

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I tried to set up a VM server in Ubuntu machine. I configure the application with the help of PuPHPet package. When I run the "vagrant up", I got the following errors:

> **1) dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or
>   directory**
>
> **2) Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call,
>   Could not find any files from** Alias /css "/var/www/css" Alias
>   /images "/var/www/images" **at
>   /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-75f35e3bc7e32744860c4bb229c88812/Apache.pp:214:18
>   on node domainname.com**
>
> **3) The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
>   assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this
>   command should be in the log above. Please read the output to
>   determine what went wrong.**

Here is the config.yaml file for the issue on Alias:

```
av_3mpni9stprhb:
        servername: domainname.com
        serveraliases:
            - '*.domainname.com'
        docroot: /var/www
        port: '80'
        setenv:
            - 'APP_ENV development'
        custom_fragment: "Alias /css \"/var/www/css\"\nAlias /images \"/var/www/images\""
        ssl: '0'
        ssl_cert: ''
        ssl_key: ''
        ssl_chain: ''
        ssl_certs_dir: ''
        ssl_protocol: ''
        ssl_cipher: ''
```

Please help me, What is the issue I made here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You missed the part that says `custom_fragment` must be a filepath containing the code, not the code itself:

[image: Read this]

Answer (score 1):

For custom_fragment,

1) you just add the file name along with path in config.yaml.

Ex: custom_fragment: `/var/www/test/alias.conf`

### In alias.conf

```
Alias /css /var/www/css

Alias /images /var/www/images
```

OR

2) just add the file path in `Virtual Host-Level Custom Directivies`.

Ex : `/var/www/test/alias.conf`

Thanks!